# Plotting a binary variable graph in excel

Tags: excel, graph, plot

Consider I have two columns named "Band"(Continuous variable) and "Risk-Flag" (1 indicating risky, 0 indicating not risky) in excel. The data would look like this:

```
Band    Risk-Flag
300     1
300     0
278     0
267     1
489     0
523     0
457     0
325     1
995     0
```

And so on.....

I need to plot (Any Type of graph will do) depicting overall risk patterns based on bands. The bands can be categorized into three levels: <250,251-350,>350.
Been working on this since days. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion: add an auxiliary column in which the individual values are replaced by class values, like this:

```
=IF(A2<=250;200;IF(A2<=350;300;400))
```

enter this formula in C2, and copy it down for all rows. If you put

```
=B2
```

in D2 (and all rows down), you can select columns C and D and insert a suitable graph.